# Как сделать кнопку "скачать"

Tags: php, css

У меня описана кнопка в  css.  И мне нужно внедрить кнопку, я не понимаю как это сделать. Есть атрибут button, но я пытался его внедрить, всё в пустую.

```css
button.new {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 
button.new:hover { background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); }
button.new:active { background: white; }
```

```html
  echo("<div style=\"position: absolute; width: 100px;    height: 50px; top: ");
  echo($i-20);
  echo("%;left:295px;"); <!--Здесь нужно внедрить кнопку  -->
  echo("</div>");
```

---

Проблема решена. Описал кнопку в html с помощью style .

Answer (score 0):

Разве не работает такая строка?

```
echo("<button class='new'>Скачать</button>");
```

Comment: Вставил ваш код. Кнопка появилась, а сам стиль не применился.

Comment: Потому что надо \ поставить перед и после new